# Can the edit button be hidden if I am unable to edit?

Tags: feature-request, edits

I keep trying to edit meta posts (often just to see how a specific formatting thing is done) but when I click edit it just tells me:

[image]

Could it be made more obvious that the post can't be edited by me? Grey it out? Hide it completely?

The 'posts edited' statistic on my profile is greyed out so I don't see why this shouldn't be...

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing the edit link shown as "disabled" (in a lighter tone of grey and inactive) for me in such cases back when I had low rep. This is really strange and counter-intuitive.

Comment: @AndriyM Maybe a consequence of the design refresh?

Comment: Related meta question [Always show the edit button on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91172/217279) I did not find a recent post related to this specific issue at https://meta.stackexchange.com so this question should be asked there, as it is not site specific, it occurs on all sites.

Comment: @JamesJenkins See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89232

Comment: @PaulWhite I concur there is nothing wrong with posting this here, but there is nothing good either. Unless it gets brought up on meta.stackexchange nothing is going to happen. It has 4 up votes here and no down votes. Change in is only going to happen if the wider community is involved.

Comment: @JamesJenkins That may or may not be true. My point was only that SE staff are just a likely to see it here as anywhere else. The success rate of feature requests over the years has not been high regardless of placement either. OTOH if it is a simple enough fix (or especially if it is a design regression) it might be addressed quickly. Ultimately, I just wanted to make sure you knew about the general guidance re: child or main meta.

Comment: I posted the question at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331212/217279